# mysql time_format function qustion

Tags: mysql, time-format

I insert and update mysql time_format function to express string value in time,

Why do some numbers get

> "truncated incorrect time value"

errors?

For example, '55' is not a problem with query, but when '188' is entered, the above error message appears.

The type is VARCHAR (50).

my query :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_HOME (DURATION) 
    VALUES (TIME_FORMAT (# {DURATION, jdbcType = VARCHAR}, '% H:% i:% s'))

UPDATE TABLE_HOME SET DURATION = TIME_FORMAT (# {DURATION, jdbcType = VARCHAR}, '% H:% i:% s')
```

Comment: As the name suggests [TIME_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) expects a time. In that context, what do `55` or `188` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TIME_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) expects a time. If you feed it with anything else, you first get a cast. In this case:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(55 AS TIME), CAST(188 AS TIME);
+------------------+-------------------+
| CAST(55 AS TIME) | CAST(188 AS TIME) |
+------------------+-------------------+
| 00:00:55         | NULL              |
+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

The [rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html#idm139843643036528) are:

> MySQL recognizes TIME values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in 'D HH:MM:SS' format. You can also use one of the following “relaxed” syntaxes: 'HH:MM:SS', 'HH:MM', 'D HH:MM', 'D HH',
>     or 'SS'. Here D represents days and can have a value from 0 to 34.
> - As a string with no delimiters in 'HHMMSS' format, provided that it makes sense as a time. For example, '101112' is understood as
>     '10:11:12', but '109712' is illegal (it has a nonsensical minute part)
>     and becomes '00:00:00'.
> - As a number in HHMMSS format, provided that it makes sense as a time. For example, 101112 is understood as '10:11:12'. The following
>     alternative formats are also understood: SS, MMSS, or HHMMSS.

In this case, #3 applies:

- `55` is rendered as `SS` so it's valid.
- `188` is not a supported format so it produces `NULL`.

Date and time handling is already hard enough. I suggest to:

1. Be explicit to avoid ambiguity (something like `23:30:45` is crystal clear, 188 is open to interpretations).
2. Not use `VARCHAR` columns to store dates and times.

Answer (score 1):

Time_Format not all integers are valid..

`188` is not a valid time anymore

Even where you placed it:

```
"%H= Hour => 188?
 %i=Minute => 188?
 %s"=Second => 188?
```

Do you think `188` is a valid time of an `Hour, Minute, Second`?